# How can I make each Thread to join in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Let me describe an example:

```
import time
import threading

def some_heavy_function():
    pass

while True:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=some_heavy_function, args=(,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=some_heavy_function, args=(,))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=some_heavy_function, args=(,))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    time.sleep(10)
```

What I want is, 1) **I don't want each thread to work again** every 10 seconds.
Each function will take more than 10 seconds, so I don't want each function to be invoked again.
So I need to use `.join()`.

But, 2) **I want each function to be invoked again** every 10 seconds if is not currently working.
In some situation,  let's say `t3` would not be invoked in the first place.
But it should be invoked after 10 seconds even while `t1` or `t2` is working.

So when you read the 1) above, you may suggest me to put

```
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
```

after three `.start()`s and before `time.sleep(10)`, 
but this makes `t3` to wait until `t1` and `t2` finish their jobs, so that `t3` is not invoked even after 10 seconds.

Of course, putting each of `.join()` method after each `.start()` method would not let me to enjoy multi-thread.

Help!

Comment: To be clear... Are you saying that each thread should be restarted after **at least** 10 seconds has elapsed?

Comment: @Cobra Yes, if certain thread is not currently working, it should be restarted after 10 seconds regardless of other threads. But if it is working it should not be restarted.

Comment: You may wonder why certain thread is not currently working, but `some_heavy_function` starts in certain situation only. That's why `time.sleep(10)` exists and it surely takes more than 10 seconds...

Comment: Why do you need `join` at all?  It sounds to me like you just want to restart threads that are no longer alive each pass through the loop.  And you are checking them every 10 seconds.

Comment: @RufusVS Because without `.join()`, running thread would be invoked again even it is currently working. I don't want another thread to be invoked again once it's invoked as mentioned in 1) above.

Comment: @HyeonPhilYoun Check the answer I poisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of control structure (a dictionary is ideal) wherein you can monitor the state of your threads.

For each thread you need to make a note of when it started. In that way you can determine how long it's been running.

You can use Thread.is_alive() to determine the state of your threads.

Here, the "heavy" function is actually a sleep for a random amount of time.

By printing the thread id (of our own making), the duration of its sleep and the actual time you can prove that this satisfies the criteria.

This code will need to be adapted in some way because, as it stands, it will run forever.

```
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time

def some_heavy_function(tid):
    ri = randint(1, 15)
    print(f'{tid} starting. Will sleep for {ri}s. Time={int(time())}')
    sleep(ri)
    print(f'{tid} ending')

NTHREADS = 3
TIME = 10
# tp is the thread reference
# st is the time that the thread was started
control = {f't{n}': {'tp': None,  'st': 0} for n in range(NTHREADS)}

while True:
    for k, v in control.items():
        if v['tp'] is not None and not v['tp'].is_alive():
            v['tp'].join()
            v['tp'] = None
        if v['tp'] is None and time() - v['st'] > TIME:
            v['tp'] = Thread(target=some_heavy_function, args=(k,))
            v['st'] = time()
            v['tp'].start()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: No never mind my previous comments I deleted. My mistakes adapting to my case, this 'control structure' is so clever. Thank you so much indeed!